# How to scroll sticky div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to scroll text content like sticky sidebar.  My reference website is https://www.workable.com/applicant-tracking?utm_campaign=capterra_ppc&utm_content=applicant-tracking&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=capterra .
Please look at the div content after the main slider. The background is fixed but the content is scrolling and image is changing. How it can be done

```css
.rpm-dash-cont {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  padding: 30px 0px;
}

.rpm-dash-cont h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.rpm-dash-cont p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="rpm-dash-cont">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>RPM Recruiting dashboard</h3>
        <p>An exact view of your recruiting process and hiring status.</p>
        <p>The recruitment dashboard provides a real time view of every job in your hiring pipeline. It further enhances by robust filters be it jobs by location, skills, resident status or departments. It also pins the most important jobs to the top of
          the page for easy access.</p>
        <p>A dynamic chart that will monitor your recruiting pipeline – see the number of candidates at every stage, for every position.</p>
        <h3>RPM Recruiting dashboard</h3>
        <p>An exact view of your recruiting process and hiring status.</p>
        <p>The recruitment dashboard provides a real time view of every job in your hiring pipeline. It further enhances by robust filters be it jobs by location, skills, resident status or departments. It also pins the most important jobs to the top of
          the page for easy access.</p>
        <p>A dynamic chart that will monitor your recruiting pipeline – see the number of candidates at every stage, for every position.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="image/dashboard.png" />
        <img class="img-responsive" src="image/dashboard-22.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for? Do you need part of that text to be sticky? if so you need to add  `position: sticky; `  in its css…

Comment: I just noticed how old this post is -_-